# How to get bool value from checkbox in javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to see if a checkbox is checked or not with a simple function. It doesn't seem to be working, here's the code:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#check').is(":checked")) {
    alert('it works')
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5h58mx1h/

Comment: First you need to add checked attribute and then try..it will alert 'it works' => try https://jsfiddle.net/8vf3uLef/

Comment: this works, if you want to get a message, when checked is changed, go for the changed event.

Comment: It's working fine - your check box is *not* checked, so you don't get the alert.

Answer (score 9):

Your code only runs once - when `document` is ready. You need to attach an event listener to the checkbox and check when it changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      alert('it works');
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2orad74y/)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need jQuery. An `<input type="checkbox">` has a [`checked` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked), which you can use like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
    alert('it works')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be work:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var ckbox = $('#checkbox');

        $('input').on('click',function () {
            if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
                alert('You have Checked it');
            } else {
                alert('You Un-Checked it');
            }
        });
    });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40e0411z/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most simple way:

```js
  if ($('#check').checked) {
    alert('it works');
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace your `HTML` to this

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked />
</form>
```

This will work for you. Because you don't checked checkbox yet that's why not alert.